# How can I assemble an equation from these guide points?

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function, quadratics, volume

For context, I am programming a building system and I want to encourage players to build with larger blocks for a given volume of world space and discourage occupying the same space, but with multiple, smaller blocks. To do this, I would like to create a function that makes larger blocks cost less per unit to create compared to smaller blocks. The block sizes are determined entirely by the player, so I cannot statically hardcode specific values for every unique size.

Now, I have a rough idea of how much certain block sizes should cost to complete, but there are two main problems I have encountered:

1. I do not know how to get the cost for sizes *in between* the sizes in the table below.
2. I do not know how to properly create an equation for the table below.

This is the table used to roughly determine the volume of material needed to "fill" or "complete" a given block/blueprint.

| Blueprint | Volume (*x*) | Fill Units (material cost) (*y*) | Volume-to-Fill Ratio (*r*) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1x1x1 Cube | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2x2x2 Cube | 8 | 4 | 0.5 |
| 4x4x4 Cube | 64 | 16 | 0.25 |
| 8x8x8 Cube | 512 | 64 | 0.125 |
| 16x16x16 Cube | 4096 | 256 | 0.0625 |
| 32x32x32 Cube | 32768 | 1024 | 0.03125 |
| 64x64x64 Cube | 262144 | 4096 | 0.015625 |

Now, how can I get an equation that given the volume of the blueprint (let's call it *x*) returns this discounted material cost/fill units (let's call it *y*). The Volume-to-Fill Ratio is there to help constructing an equation. It is the rate of change or let's call it *r*.

It is my understanding that this should roughly be an equation like $y=x*r$ or something similar to that. However, how do I find *r*, given just the blueprint volume (*x*)?

Alternatively, if there is a better way to structure the equation, that would be welcome too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 2, your table has $y=\sqrt[3]{x^2}$ and $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$.

For question 1, I think you can just use the same equation as above. If it has to be an integer value, you can use the floor function as well.

Comment: So, far, it looks like the equation fits perfectly with my data points! Thank you very much, kind stranger!